# Intensity of Exponential Distribution

Tags: distribution

How do I show the following:
Suppose $\lambda=-\frac{S'(x)}{S(x)}$, where $S(x)=1-F(x)$ is survival probability.
Show that $\lambda$ is the intensity of the exponential distribution with cdf $F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$.

Comment: I think the way the question is worded is awkward. I would have said: Suppose the intensity function defined by $\lambda(x)=\frac{S^{'}(x)}{S(x)}$ is equal to a constant $\lambda$. Show that in this case the cdf of the distribution is the cdf of an exponential, which is $F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$. And you verify this by plugging in the $F(x)$ in the previous expression and seeing that you do indeed get a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define an intensity function, and you might be assuming what's to be shown. Does this help?
\begin{align*}
-\frac{S'(x)}{S(x)} &= \lambda\frac{e^{-\lambda x}}{e^{-\lambda x} } \tag{defn of survival function} \\
&= 1.
\end{align*}